# Where I can find the appWizard that can generate C++ application

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have an project to modify. This project was create with AppWizard many years ago. This generated weird code when I open it with visual studio 8. I would like to modify the interface. Can I find a free AppWizard.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Does this Microsoft Support article help:
[How to migrate a Visual C++ 6.0 custom AppWizard to a Visual C++ .NET custom wizard](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810455)